# Transformar um for em lambda com interação de variavel

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, java-8

Como transformo o trecho abaixo em um código Lambda?

A ideia é multiplicar o `maxScore` pelo `i` para que a cada interação ele suba o numero, **apenas para os 5 primeiros** resultados.

```
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        list.get(i).setScore(maxScore + (0.01d * i));
    }
```

A ideia do codigo é mais ou menos essa:

```
    List<HashObject> list = createObjects(10);
    Double maxScore = 0.9d;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        list.get(i).setScore(maxScore + (0.01d * i));
    }
```

Classe HashObject:

```
    public class HashObject {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private Double score;

        /* Getters and Setters */
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Senhores,

Resolvi o problema com o comando:

```
IntStream.range(0,5).forEach(p -> list.get(p).setScore(0.01d * (double)p));
```

Sendo que o comando **IntStream.range(0,5)** faz o loop, **forEach** percorri o loop e o *p* é a interação do loop (o **i** no caso do for).

Answer (score 0):

Opa, então você pega os elementos da sua lista e aplica um forEach:

Exemplo:

```
  List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

  list.forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));
```

Qualquer coisa olha esse link:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-usar-funcoes-lambda-em-java/32826

Comment: Bruno, a qualidade da resposta com toda certeza pode ser melhorada! Exemplifique com uma aplicação que possa ser executada ou coisa do tipo..

Comment: Só o forEach não serve, pois preciso que o valor dentro score esta incrementado para cada interação do Loop.Ex.: quando i for igual a 0 ele não vai somar nada ao maxScore, quando o i for igual 1 ele tem que somar 0,01 no maxScore, quando o i for igual a 2 ele tem que somar 0,02 no max score.

Comment: Preciso fazer exatamente a mesma coisa que este loop faria só que com lambda